# Chrome skipping last second of video

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

See http://jsfiddle.net/VjsQH/. You'll notice that the `currentTime` output normally increments by 0.25 seconds or so, but once it reaches 7, then jumps immediate to 8 (the duration of the video).

It appears that Chrome is skipping the last second of the video. This does not happen in Safari or Firefox.

This seems like an open-and-shut bug. Perhaps the code is testing for video end using

```
if (time > duration - 1)
```

instead of the correct

```
if (time >= duration)
```

but is there some chance I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding the spec? This bug may have remained well-hidden because hey, who would notice a missing second, especially at the end since the final frame normally sits up there on the screen anyway, but in my case I am triggering off the `ended` event to do other things and need the final second to play out in all its glory.

In the meantime I have reported this bug, assuming it is one, against Chrome.

Comment: I don't repro that (Win8, Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m); with your test I see : 0 0.251 0.504 ... 6.766 7.016 7.266 7.517 7.767 8

Comment: That's very odd, I have exactly the same OS and Chrome version. For me it goes: 0 0.257 0.501 ... 6.526 6.777 7.028 8.

Comment: I ran into the same thing and submitted a bug:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419983